# Getting the largest value from an object in a list in another list [C#]

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a big broblem.

I have a TaskGroup object. Each TaskGroup has:
a 'Task' object and a List < TaskGroup > . (has a list of objects of itself in it). It is supposed to be a tree.

Having a 'TaskGroup' object that has 'List ' in it.
I need to get the single largest Date value from the 'Task' object in each object in the 'TaskGroup' list.

```
public class TaskGroup
{
  public ProjectTask Task { get; set;}
  public List<TaskGroup> ChildTask { get; set; } = new List<TaskGroup>();
}
public class Task
{
  public int Id { get; set;}
  public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

In the diagram - having "my object" I have to get the largest date marked in red.

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks

Comment: FYI, collection names should be plural, like `ChildTasks`

Comment: do you need to go only 1 level deep or there can be more levels? like task.ChildTask.First().ChildTask -> and there can be max date that you want to get?

Comment: And does this include the current `TaskGroup.Task` or just the children?

Comment: I am in model class 'TaskGroup' and I want to do an internal method that gets the largest date from List <TaskGroup> -> Task -> Date. One date for the entire List <TaskGroup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the largest date from the immediate children, you can just use a simple Linq statement:

```
var maxDate = taskGroup.ChildTask.Max(c => c.Task.Date);
```

To get the max date from all taskGroups under the main taskGroup, you can recursively check all the children for their max date:

```
static DateTime GetMaxDate(TaskGroup group)
{
    if (group == null) return DateTime.MinValue;

    var maxDate = group.Task?.Date ?? DateTime.MinValue;

    foreach (var child in group.ChildTask)
    {
        if (child.Task?.Date > maxDate) maxDate = child.Task.Date;

        foreach (var taskGroup in child.ChildTask)
        {
            var childMax = GetMaxDate(taskGroup);
            if (childMax > maxDate) maxDate = childMax.Date;
        }
    }

    return maxDate;
}
```